# Migration of Angular 5 to Angular 6

Tags: typescript, migration, angular5, angular-cli, angular6

I am following Angular migration tutorial to migrate from Angular 5 to 6.

https://update.angular.io/

After completing the entire process of migration, on trying to run application using ng serve, an error appears

> The Angular CLI configuration format has been changed, and your existing configuration
>   can be updated automatically by running the following command: ng update @angular/cli

I did as recommended but the issue still persists.

Angular Cli 6+ have angular.json instead of angular-cli.json. But shouldn't it be updated while updating the package.

I referred their git conversation. It says to use ng update and the file structure would automatically update, but mine haven't.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a method to solve this, since no one posted any answer I am posting it, as it may help someone.

The Issue was with the json file, I removed the .angular-cli.json file and replaced it with a newly created angular 6 app's json file , and run npm install. It solved my issue.

Steps:
1 : remove .angular-cli.json
2 : create a new angular6 app and copy its angular.json
3 : run npm install

This is just a work-around and I presume direct migration works in normal cases.